# Does rate of expansion of the universe affect perceived strength of gravitational pull?

Tags: gravity, orbital-motion, space-expansion, dark-energy

As I understand expansion of the universe could be viewed as a constant negative pressure. So when we are looking at two bodies like Earth and Sun, from their perspective there should be a force acting outwards. In that case when we measure the force of gravity between two bodies it should be tiny tiny bit smaller than actual value of that force.
Is that correct thinking? If so how small the force emerging from expansion of the universe is in contrast to the force of gravity between Earth and Sun?

Comment: I'm out of my depth here, but doesn't the principle of relativity say that the force you measure is in fact the "actual" force?

Comment: Yes but it might be a resultant of few different forces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in theory the gravitational force is slightly smaller than it would be without the cosmological constant. To a good approximation, it's as though space is filled with matter with a density of $-2 Ω_Λ ρ_c \approx -1.2\times 10^{-29} \text{ g/cm}^3$.

By the shell theorem, the effect of this matter on earth's orbit is roughly as though the sun was lighter by $\frac43 π R^3 ρ \approx 2\times 10^{8} \text{ kg}$ (where $R$ is the radius of the orbit, not of the sun). The sun's mass is about $2\times 10^{30} \text{ kg}$. To detect such a small discrepancy we'd need to know its mass to 22 decimal places, which we don't. In fact, the sun emits about 380 yottawatts of power, which is $4\times 10^9 \text{ kg/s}$ (dividing by $c^2$), so its mass changes by more than the theoretical discrepancy over very short time scales.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was missing. I had no idea how to calculate this giving cosmological constant as km/s/mpc